# Problema con VENTANA MODAL. Quiero mostrar 2 en una misma pagina

Tags: php, javascript, modal

como el nombre ya dice la idea es mostrar 2 ventanas modales diferentes, por medio de 2 botones, diferentes tb claro. Por medio de un tuto consegui mostrar una ventana donde listo mis clientes, mi problema es para mostrar la segunda, no se como identificar los 2 modales. les paso los codigos por si alguno pueda dar una mano:

**aca llamo a la primera modal**

```
<div class="col-md-6">
     <label for="">Cliente:</label>
     <div class="input-group">
     <input type="hidden" name="idcliente" id="idcliente">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" disabled="disabled" id="cliente">
     <span class="input-group-btn">
     <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-default" ><span class="fa fa-search"></span> Buscar</button>
                                    </span>
```

**aca defino el cuerpo de la modal**

```
<div class="modal-body">
            <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Nombre</th>
                        <th>Tipo de Doc</th>
                        <th>Documento</th>
                        <th>Opcion</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php if(!empty($clientes)):?>
                          <?php foreach ($clientes as $cliente):?> 

                            <tr>
                              <td> <?php echo $cliente->id_cliente;?> </td>
                              <td> <?php echo $cliente->nombres_cliente;?> </td>
                              <td> <?php echo $cliente->TipoDocumento;?> </td>
                              <td> <?php echo $cliente->num_documento_cliente;?> </td>

                              <?php $dataCliente = $cliente->id_cliente."*".$cliente->nombres_cliente."*".$cliente->telefono_cliente."*".$cliente->email_cliente."*".$cliente->direccion_cliente."*".$cliente->TipoCliente."*".$cliente->TipoDocumento."*".$cliente->num_documento_cliente;?>

                              <td> 
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-check" value="<?php echo $dataCliente;?>"><span class="fa fa-check"></span></button>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          <?php endforeach;?> 
                        <?php endif;?>  
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

**este es su controlador**

```
$(document).on("click",".btn-check",function()
{
    cliente = $(this).val();
    infocliente = cliente.split("*");
    $("#idcliente").val(infocliente[0]);
    $("#cliente").val(infocliente[1]);
    $("#modal-default").modal("hide");
})
```

cuales son los campos que debo modificar para identificar las ventanas modal?
apartir de este ejemplo que podria cambiar para hacer otro llamado para listar mis productos?

AGRADECIDO POR LA AYUDA, Salodos!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo que deberías hacer en este caso es asignar un id a cada uno de los modales ejemplo:

```
<div class="modal-body" id="modalCliente">
```

luego para hacer referencia a este modal lo haces de la siguiente manera

```
$("#modalCliente").modal("hide");
```

Comment: Creo que deberías mencionar también la creación del segundo botón haciendo referencia al modal... algo así por ejemplo: `<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalCliente" ><span class="fa fa-user"></span> Cliente</button>`

Comment: Gracias amigos x la ayuda.. Me solucionaron mi el problema!! excelente!! Saludos.